# Ansible group_vars

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to automate the deployment of sensu checks to each role that a host plays.

I currently have a structure like

```
group_vars/
  nginx
  all
```

In each group_vars file, I have defined the following:

```
sensu_checks:
  - check_name
  - check_other_name
```

So for example, in group_vars/all I'd have:

```
sensu_checks:
  - check_raid
  - check_load
  - check_disk
```

In group_vars/nginx I'd have:

```
sensu_checks:
 - check_pid
 - check_http
```

What I would like to know if it's possible would be to get all the checks that a specific host should install, for example with:

```
- name: Print host sensu checks
  command: echo {{item}}
  with_flattened:
   - {{ sensu_checks }}
```

This doesn't work though, as it only gives me the group_vars of the last group the host name is defined in. Is there a way to get a flattened list the checks of all the groups the host is attached to?

In the previous example, I'd expect

```
 [ check_load, check_disk, check_raid, check_http, check_pid ]
```

but instead I'm getting

```
[ check_http, check_pid ]
```

for an nginx host (which is part of both the 'all' and and 'nginx' groups)

Answer (score 2):

`with_flattened` doesn't do what you expect in this case - you're a victim of [variable scoping](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

The `nginx` group is the most specific, so ansible is using that variable definition - which explains why you're only getting the `sensu_check` defined in `nginx`.

You could rename the var in one of the two places (I recommend the nginx var, since that's the most specific one), and then use `with_flattened` to combine the two lists:

`with_flattened:
   - {{ sensu_checks }}
   - {{ sensu_nginx_checks }}`

Answer (score 0):

In your question the YAML format is incorrect for group_vars/all

It should look like:

```
sensu_checks:
  - check_raid
  - check_load
  - check_disk
```

If that is the code in your project you might want to fix it and see if you get the result you are expecting.

Comment: My bad, the YAML mark up was correct, I've edited the post. If I remove the specific host from the nginx group, then I do get the vars from all, but I'm struggling to get the checks from all the groups of a host, not just the one that was defined last