# Merging nested variables from group_vars in Ansible

Tags: ansible

It looks like Ansible is not able to merge nested variables from group_vars. My structure is like:
`hosts.ini`:

```
[common:children]
frontend
backend

[frontend]
server1

[backend]
server2
```

in `groups-vars` directory I have:

`common.yaml`:

```
start_of_nested variables:
  var1: value1
  var2: value2
```

`frontend.yaml`:

```
start_of_nested variables:
  var3: value3
  var4: value4
```

`backend.yaml`:

```
start_of_nested variables:
  var5: value5
  var6: value6
```

when I check `server1` variables with:

```
ansible server1 -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]"
```

I get variables only from `frontend.yaml`:

```
"start_of_nested": {
            "var3": "value3",
            "var4": "value4"
}
```

but I was expecting that they will be merged with `common.yaml` variables and I will get sth like

```
"start_of_nested": {
            "var1": "value1",
            "var2": "value2",
            "var3": "value3",
            "var4": "value4"
}
```

Is there any way that Ansible will merge nested variables for a host from `group_vars` which it belongs to?

Comment: it's not related to my question, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261093/ansible-group-vars) is more related but I don't understand why Ansible is not mergin nested variables which make a lot of problems in designinq group_vars in inventory

Comment: "*I was expecting that they will be merged*" -- what was your expectation based on?

Comment: @techraf my expectation was based on common sense, let say I have genera role for user creation which base on nested `user:` variable which is a list of users like `{"name": "someuser", "groups": ["sudo", "some_group"] }` and I would like to add sys admins in `common.yaml` group_vars and some extra DBAs in `mysql.yaml` group_vars so I don't need to create extra variable for users like `db_users`

Comment: What if variable is a string, a list, a number? How do you merge them? And if you replace strings, lists, numbers, isn't common sense to replace dictionaries too?　・　And it's British spelling for "behaviour" in the option... that's why I could not find the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing correct parameter, what about merging I used to use SaltStack and it handles this without problem so I think it shouldn't be hard even with lists which you pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525546/ansible-host-in-multiple-groups) they are not supported by `hash_behaviour = merge`

Comment: "*I think it shouldn't be hard even with lists*" ― Lists are ordered. What would determine order if they were merged automagically?

Comment: I can't find any usecase where I will need ordered lists in my variables, lets say I have list of user dictionaries or list of packages I want to install I don't care about the order in those lists.

Comment: List are ordered in YAML (and in JSON). That's how it was decided in the specification, regardless of your use cases.